# How to set up and use Rails environment variables in production server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, github

I need to set up an environment variable for my rails app. Both in my local machine and in the production server. I read some tutorials on the internet but NONE has given the complete instruction on how to set and use these variable in the actual production server. I use digital ocean and linux server to host my rails app.

I have spent days trying to figure this out, but still haven't found a clear and complete instruction from setting the variables on my local machine -> push it to git repo -> set and use the variables in production server. So, hope somebody can help me here, thanks!

**UPDATE:**

This is how I currently setup the environment variables in my rails app by using figoro gem:

[image]

Comment: have you seen this https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

Comment: @Arv I have seen it, but still I dont undertand how do I use this gem so that I could use it in my production server. I cannot find it in their documentation. The "Getting Started" part of the readme only mention on how could i set and use these variables on my local machine. But then how about the production server?

Comment: it would be same as u used in localsystem, you need to export those value in your production server , which server u are using?

Comment: That's wierd. In my localsystem, i never have to do anything except for writing all my environment variables in application.yml file. This is exactly what i did for my localsystem, and I just followed what figoro documentation told me. The only question now, what should I do in my production server? I cannot use the same method like I did in my localsystem because the application.yml file is no longer available. Btw, im using windows for my localsystem and linux for my production server

Comment: share your code how you are defining it, so that other can give u better answer .

Comment: @Arv ok done..you can see it on my update

Comment: as you have defined it in yml it is looking like you want to setup secret code , I have added answer please find it .

Answer (score 3):

You can set system-wide environment variables in the /etc/rc.local file (which is executed when the system boots). If your Rails app is the sole user of the Linux system, that is a good place to store credentials such as API keys because there is no risk of including this file in a public Git repository, as it is outside the application directory. The secrets will only be vulnerable if the attacker gains shell access to your Linux server.

Set the environment variables within /etc/rc.local (do not include the <> characters):

```
export SOME_LOGIN=<username>
export SOME_PASS=<password>
```

To see the value of an environment variable, use one of the following commands in the Linux shell:

```
printenv MY_VAR
echo $MY_VAR
```

To access those environment variables within Rails, use the following syntax:

Inside .rb files or at the rails console

```
ENV['MY_VAR']
```

Inside .yml files:

```
<%= ENV['MY_VAR'] %>
```

Answer (score 2):

- I believe we should not push a secret file on git.
- To ignore such file use gitignore file and push other code on the git.
- On the server side just copy the secret file and create a symlink for that file.
  You can find demo here http://www.elabs.se/blog/57-handle-secret-credentials-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still having this issue, figaro now has an easy method in setting the production variables in heroku. Just run:

```
$ figaro heroku:set -e production
```

Answer (score 1):

ryzalyusoff.

### For Unix

You can use **LINUX ENV** in rails application.

```
# .env
GITHUB_SECRET_KEY=SECRET
TWITTER_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXX
# in rails code
puts ENV["TWITTER_ACCESS_KEY"] # => SECRET
```

Create .env files for local machine and your production server. Export environment variables like this(**on server with ssh**):

```
export GITHUB_SECRET_KEY="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

Anyway, storing keys in config - bad idea. Just add `.env.example`, others keys configs add to `.gitignore`. Goodluck.

[Example with Rails](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html)

### For Windows

```
Syntax
  SET variable
  SET variable=string
  SET /A "variable=expression"
  SET "variable="
  SET /P variable=[promptString]
  SET "
Key
  variable    : A new or existing environment variable name e.g. _num
  string      : A text string to assign to the variable.
  expression  : Arithmetic expression
```

[Windows CMD](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

Comment: I linux for my production sever but in my local machine I use windows. Will I still able to use this method? And why do I need to run the export command if I have set the .env files for both my local machine and my production server?

Comment: @ryzalyusoff, because your keys can be different, for example. And yes, you can use this way on Windows [example](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html), but not tested by me. Create example .env file with names of keys and try to manage variables, you dont need install libraries or something. But `figaro` - is not bad solution. Just try.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your environment variables in production in the same way, you do it for local system. However, there are couple of gems, which make it easier to track and push to production. Have a look at [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro). This will help you in setting up and deployment of env vars.

Comment: Hey thank. But may I know how to push my environment variables to the production server by using this gem?

Comment: on the gem readme available on github, [link](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro#other-hosts) it lists the way, in which you can deploy the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with  [figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)
or in rails 4 there is a file named secret.yml in config folder where you can define your environment variables this file is by default in .gitignore file.For production you need to manually copy that file to server for security reason so that your sensitive information is not available to any one

Comment: I have taken a look at Figoro gem. The problem is people say "there is a file named secret.yml in config folder where you can define your environment variables this file is by default in .gitignore file". If i did that, how is my production server suppose to read these variables from my local machine? And if i need to copy this file manually to my production server, in which directory i suppose to put it? And what command should i run/type afterward?

Comment: You can add this file with same name secret.yml or any name  the file defined in config folder with extension .yml variables by default loaded in environment.And you don't need to run any command for that just copy that file with scp command to server

Comment: If need to deploy that app on Heroku server go through this link "https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars"

Comment: I see. But isn't this a bad way of doing this? Because I am using git as my version control. If use this way, every time that I push a new updates to my production server, I need to add this file manually. Which is troublesome :/

Comment: Its not about git its about security .You share your repo with a lot of people but don't want to share your credential for braintree(Payment option) or something very sensitive like live database crediential which you don't want to share

Comment: Yeah I agree and understand what you mean and thank you for helping me out. But I just want to know if there is a better way of doing this. Or is this how people usually do?

Comment: I currently don't know if you get anything better update on this thread also

Answer (score 0):

First create your variable like:

```
MY_ENV_VAR="this is my var"
```

And then make it global:

```
export MY_ENV_VAR
```

You can check if the process succeeded with:

```
printenv
```

Or:

```
echo MY_ENV_VAR
```

Comment: How to make the variable global? And if i have 10 variables to set, isn't this a troublesome?

Comment: You can make a bash script or something